# How to create @Projection for complex @Entity objects?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, spring-rest

I'd like to expose a very complex `@Entity` object via `spring-data-rest`. Therefore I'm trying to create a simple `@Projection` and at first would like to expose just one field of the entity for testing. But even this fails:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(PersonProjection.class)
interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> (){

}

@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    private long id;

    private String name;

    //many more properties  

    @ManyToOne
    ...

    @OneToOne
    ...
}

@Projection(name = "personProjection", types = Person.class)
public interfaace PersonProjection {
    String name();
}
```

Result:

Infinite loop of:

```
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.mapping.LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.doWithAssociation(LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.java:101)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:352)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.mapping.LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.doWithAssociation(LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.java:101)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:352)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.mapping.LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.doWithAssociation(LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.java:101)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:352)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.mapping.LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.doWithAssociation(LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.java:101)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:352)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.mapping.LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.doWithAssociation(LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.java:101)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:352)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.mapping.LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.doWithAssociation(LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.java:101)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:352)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.mapping.LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.doWithAssociation(LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.java:101)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:352)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.mapping.LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.doWithAssociation(LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.java:101)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithAssociations(BasicPersistentEntity.java:352)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.mapping.LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.doWithAssociation(LinkCollectingAssociationHandler.java:101)
```

Question: what might be the cause here? How can I quickly just expose one simple string property of that class?

Comment: Did you have a circular data reference? see bug: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-396

Comment: @hasnae yes but I annotated each of the child-entities with `@RestResource(exported = false) @JsonIgnore`, plus I created each one a `CrudRepository`. Still this endless loop occurs.